# CSS Round uppr corners of table row

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I am setting the background color of table rows to give them a visual presence.  I've been stymied in doing something I thought would be pretty simple which is rounding the corners of a row.  I've created a class that works on a whole table but can't get it to work on the row.  (Can't put it on whole table as table has some stuff in it that should not be rounded.)  Have tried putting the class in the table row, the table cell inside it and span all to no avail.  Would appreciate any suggestions.

css

```
<head>
    <style>
        .rounded { 
            -moz-border-radius: 15px; 
            border-radius: 15px; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

html

```
<table>
    <tr><td colspan=3 >Some stuff at top of table where background is white</td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color:silver" class="rounded">
        <td colspan=3 class="rounded"><span class="rounded">Text where background is shaded where I want background shaded</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Delete the `<head>` tags in your CSS. Why are those there?

Comment: Your code is creating rounded corners on the `<tr>` you're specifying. I don't see a problem. http://jsfiddle.net/6x2Kf/

Comment: I am looking at your jsfiddle in Firefox and don't see rounded corners.  Do you see them in other browser?  If so problem could be with with my moz..

Comment: Yes you're right. It is not showing in Firefox. Chrome works fine though.

Comment: in Firefox that radius is applied only to the border, not to the background, look here: http://jsfiddle.net/6x2Kf/1/

Comment: Ok.  I put the background color in the css and that seemed to fix it as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question will probably help you out (doesn't look like it's possible to achieve rounded corners on tables rows... at least not in all browsers.):

[CSS3 border-radius on display:table-row element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214686/css3-border-radius-on-displaytable-row-element)

*Note: This question is regarding displaying divs as rows but it is equivalent to using rows.*