# Jquery Mobile tables with rounded edges

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm busy using reflow tables in jquery mobile. I would like to have the 1st and last rows of my table to have rounded edges. I'm using the following code:

```
th:first-child {
   -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
   -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
   border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}

th:last-child {
   -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
   border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}
```

The HTML is similar to this;

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First column</th>
        <th>Second column</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Row one, cell one</td>
        <td>Row one, cell two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row two, cell one</td>
        <td>Row two, cell two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row three, cell one</td>
        <td>Row four, cell two</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I would literally just want the top most and bottom most cell to have rounded edges.

Comment: Are you sure they're the ones with the border and not `table` or `tr`?

Comment: I've tried just using table and making the tables borders round but nothing seems to happen when I do that. I've also tried tr and it does work with tr but only when is say tr:first-child td... which makes all the columns rounded but when I just have tr:first-child then nothing happens

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes a little close...

```
thead tr:first-child th:first-child {
   -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
   -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
   border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}

thead tr:first-child th:last-child {
   -moz-border-radius: 0px 6px 0 0;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0px 6px 0 0;
   border-radius: 0px 6px 0 0;
}

tr:last-child td:first-child{
   -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 6px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 6px;
   border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 6px;
}

tr:last-child td:last-child{
   -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
   border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Close enough for me! Thank you so much for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the element's display property, [thi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257130/2079707)s should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It works by giving the table itself the border properties:

```
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/axuruz/2/edit)