# Borders not showing in card like div structure

Tags: jquery, html, css, border, bootstrap-4

For some reason, even if i'm using the same color for the outside boder and the inside one, the borders inside do not show. Can anyone help me show the borders on the inside and the outside?

PS: i tried changing the color, it did not work.

```
<div id="card">

  <div style="display: table; height: 300px; width: 200px; padding: 0px; border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.121569); font-size: 16px; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <div style="display: table-row; height: 24px; padding: 12px 20px; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.121569); background-color: rgb(247, 247, 249);">Header</div>
    <div style="display: table-row; padding: 20px;">Body</div>
    <div style="display: table-row; height: 24px; padding: 12px 20px; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.121569); background-color: rgb(247, 247, 249);">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/24qLhtto/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div id="card">

  <div style="display: table; border-collapse: collapse;  height: 300px; width: 200px; padding: 0px; border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.121569); font-size: 16px; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <div style="display: table-row; height: 24px; padding: 12px 20px; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.121569); background-color: rgb(247, 247, 249);">Header</div>
    <div style="display: table-row; padding: 20px;">Body</div>
    <div style="display: table-row;z-index:10; height: 24px; padding: 12px 20px; border: 1px solid red; background-color: rgb(247, 247, 249);">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here you go:

https://jsfiddle.net/24qLhtto/2/

All you needed to do was to add: 
`border-collapse: collapse;`
to your parent div. That happens when you have `display: table;` you have to pay special attention to borders on tables.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you also help me with the border-radius? It's not showing.

Comment: @DumitruDaniel take a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257130/7654934) answer. Hope this helps, and also may I ask you to upvote and mark this answer as Accepted, so future visitors can solve their issue easy and fast? Thanks!

Comment: In my case, i don't have a child div for the display:table-row div :( Does this mean i need to add another containter div around the three divs that have display: table-row?

Comment: @DumitruDaniel https://jsfiddle.net/24qLhtto/4/  I believe this is the only way that you can make a "border-radius" around it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
<div id="card">

  <div style="display: table; height: 300px; width: 200px; padding: 0px; border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.121569); font-size: 16px; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);border-collapse: collapse">
    <div style="display: table-row; height: 24px; padding: 12px 20px; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.121569); background-color: rgb(247, 247, 249);">Header</div>
    <div style="display: table-row; padding: 20px;">Body</div>
    <div style="display: table-row; height: 24px; padding: 12px 20px; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.121569); background-color: rgb(247, 247, 249);">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

add `border-collapse: collapse` to `display: table`

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/24qLhtto/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way I look at this issue,  because i ran into the following problems:
-don't use `display:table`, with `display: row`. If you do, borders will not display correctly, unless you also use `border-collapse: collapse`, in which case border-radius will not work. I used `display:flex` instead.

https://codepen.io/dumitrudan608/pen/eEdPVG